# eclipse not showing Avd manager window and android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm using *Windows 7* and *Eclipse Helios*. I installed all packages successfully and I could run `avd` on the command line, but *Eclipse* was not showing the *AVD Manager* window and my android project. Why?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

I know its a bit late answer but for future generations - this is how its done:
Click on Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab.
Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and hit the OK button.

Comment: Mine just randomly disappeared on me.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 10):

Before doing what user1450537 said, check to see if you're in the Java perspective. I was in the PHP perspective and couldn't find it! *duh*

Comment: Thanks alexg. I had the "Java EE" tab selected. I changed to "Java" and now it works. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is for new eclipse Neon:

Window ->Perspective -> Customize perspective -> Action Set Availability then  Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and hit the OK button.