# Don't see Android SDK and AVD Manager when execute android tool command

Tags: android, macos, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm developing android on Mac OS.

In the first time, I use *android* tool command (`<sdk>`/tools/android) to launch **Android SDK and AVD Manager** as this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html. It's OK. In Mac OS, the program's UI is same as in Windows as the images in the link.

But now, when I run that command, it only start Android SDK Manager as the image below:

[image]

How do I revert it? Please help

Comment: Go to your android-sdk/tools folder and double click on android.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So you are missing the AVD mannager? This newer update has separate executables for SDK and AVD, so you don't have to wait the SDK to update library. The "AVD manager" executable resides in the same folder as the "SDK manager". Try manualy navigating there. I don't use Mac so I can't help you there, but it should be in the same folder.

Answer (score 41):

From the Terminal change to the `<sdk>/tools/` directory and type the following to display the AVD Manager window (I'm using android-sdk r15):

`$ android avd`

Comment: I needed to run `./android avd`

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded and installed Android 4.0.3 (API 15) today and there is no "avd" tool in the /tools/ or the /platform-tools/ folder. However, you can access the Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD Manager) through the Android SDK Manager.

- execute the "android" tool with no arguments in the "Tools" window,
- select "Manage AVDs"

Answer (score 4):

Credit to user1450537 who gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323067/eclipse-not-showing-avd-manager-window-and-android-project):

"I know its a bit late answer but for future generations - this is how its done: Click on Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab. Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and hit the OK button."

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command line for opening Android SDK Manager, but make sure Android SDK manager is installed in your machine.

Use this command in terminal: `./android avd`

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the AVD manager to the menu. in Default Preferences I navigated to 
Appearance & Behavior > Menus & Toolbars

I found AVD Manager under
Main Menu > Tools > Android
I clicked on AVD Manager, then clicked "Add After" and found the tools menu, and added the item inside the tools menu. Restarted AndroidStudio, and the menu item was there under a submenu

Comment: Haha omg, that is the dumbest thing ever, if that was the reason :) only on android development!

Comment: For whatever reason, in Android Studio 3.1 on Mac the enter Android menu option wasn't showing up, and doing this was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

On the Run Configurations screen, there is a "Manager..." button, which will open up the AVD Manager.  You must first select "Automatically pick compatible device..." to enable the "Manager..." button.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android tool, you can select from the menu bar `Tool` then `Manage AVDs...`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the SDK is installed in the `opt` folder, you could try the following command:

```
sudo /opt/android-sdk/tools/android ; exit;
```

This will open the SDK manager.
You need the *sudo* as often the storing folder (opt in this case) is protected from writing.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. You are not in java perspective. Open going to Window -> Open Perspective -> Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `<sdk>/tools` to your `PATH` if you use it often. Open your `~/.bashrc` file and add this line:

```
# <sdk> is path to your SDK, e.g. /Users/akarienta/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:<sdk>/tools
```

Then just reload the file by `source ~/.bashrc` or restart the terminal. Since now you can use commands like these (in whatever location you are):

```
# opens Android SDK Manager
$ android
# opens Android AVD Manager
$ android avd
```