# Open Avd Manager on MacOSX Without an IDE

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

It seems like a simple enough question but I don't know how to do it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119282/dont-see-android-sdk-and-avd-manager-when-execute-android-tool-command) question would suggest that I need to open the "android" unix exec file and pass in some parameters. But I'll be damned if I can find out which params.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  There may be better/easier alternatives.

Comment: The graphic designer at my company need to run some emulators

Answer (score 0):

From the command line type:

```
$>emulator -avd yourAvdName.avd
```

You will need to install the Android SDK in order to be able to do this (and have a properly configured AVD on the environment, etc).

You cannot run an emulator without at least having the Android SDK installed, you don't necessarily need an IDE, but you do need the SDK.

If you want to access the SDK tools without using the IDE, you can type this at the command line:

```
$>android
```

Comment: the sdk is installed, I want to open the avd manager to configure and start an emultor. I don't want to open an emultor from command line

Comment: in the most recent android tools this only opens the sdk manager