# Cordova/Phonegap confusion

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm new to both tools. I'm trying to get a sample application working, a flashlight app that I saw on github. I'm using OSX. I've created a project and added the platform too, android. However, I'm not sure how to start the application.

I was reading this stackoverflow post and the guy mentions that android sdk and platform tools are needed, [Phonegap/cordova add Android Platform on Mac not recognized as core cordova platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584541/phonegap-cordova-add-android-platform-on-mac-not-recognized-as-core-cordova-plat) Where can I find those?

Since I was curious, I ran phonegap run android and below is what I got then it went back to the prompt. Nothing happened.

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android'
```

Fyi, this is what is in my directory right now

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 user01  207825898  102 Dec 23 12:15 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x  6 user01  207825898  204 Dec 23 12:19 www/
-rw-r--r--  1 user01  207825898  992 Dec 23 12:32 config.xml
drwxr-xr-x  6 user01  207825898  204 Dec 23 12:32 plugins/
drwxr-xr-x  4 user01  207825898  136 Dec 23 12:32 platforms/
```

And this is my unix history output

```
$ cordova create .
$ ls -lrt
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin
$ cordova platform add android
```

Then I ran this

```
$ cordova build
```

However, I got an error

```
Running command: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/build
[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/user01/repos/Flash/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

What am I missing? I watched a tutorial in youtube and the person used Eclipse. Do I really need an Eclipse editor to be able to start a phonegap application? I was hoping I can just copy the build directory into an Apache server then visit the webserver from a phone. However, I'm not sure if I do it this way, I'm missing the purpose of phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ANDROID_HOME` system variable to the location of your Android sdk. Also add the `bin` folder of your Android sdk to the system variable `path`.

Cordova looks for the Android sdk and binaries by evaluating those two variables.

Comment: Ok, looks like i need to install android sdk? I'll google it. Is there such thing as sdk platform? That's what the person mentioned on the so I included in my post

Comment: If you want to build apps for Android you ll need the sdk. Çordova just lure you into thinking HTML and JavaScript is everything you need.

Comment: Yes you will find the sdk as standalone to download.

Comment: In the the bin folder should be a executable called sdkmanager. Run it to install platforms and build tools.

Comment: ok, trying it now. I had a question above. Am I right that I really don't need Eclipse to start the app?

Comment: No eclipse needed (opt for Android Studio if you want native development).

Comment: Ok. I finished downloading the standalone sdk. I moved it to /usr/local/bin so now I have /usr/local/bin/android-sdk-macosx. I've also assigned this to ANDROID_HOME. I searched for the bin directory and I found it in tools/apps/SdkController/bin. Is this the one I need to add to PATH?

Comment: Could be. I cannot say because I have no Mac. You should find the sdkmanager or similar tooling in this folder.

Comment: No, should be .sh not .apk.

Comment: I downloaded this specifically the one for mac osx - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other This one -> android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip

Comment: Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8119282/1087479 without Mac I can't help you that much. You just need to setup the path variable and start the sdkmanager to download platforms and build tools. Good luck.

Comment: I got it working. I found it from their docs. I had to run android sdk to download tools, platforms, etc :) This is the page that helped me - http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to have 2 platforms on a single project such as android and wp8? Or should I duplicate the directory and use separate platform for each?

Comment: Should be possible. This is what Cordova claims to be capable of. But you should ask the "how" in a different question.