# Android Virtual Device does not run

Tags: android

In Eclipse, I click Window > Android Virtual Device Manager, then highlight a AVD I created (by the first app instructions) and click Start. The AVD Options dialogue pops up, I click OK (or something) the "starting AVD progress indicator screen" pops up, the progress bar shows progress up to completion. And then nothing, no AVD is visible.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

computer is Win XP with latest download of adt-bundle-windows-x86.

Comment: **"...I click OK (or something)..."** - "or something"??? If you're not sure what it is you click then how can any of us be expected to work out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this - Click on Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab. Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and click the OK button.

This post helps - [eclipse not showing Avd manager window and android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323067/eclipse-not-showing-avd-manager-window-and-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed ARM EABI? Or some other system image? The AVD won't start if you dont specify one CPU/ABI.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it just takes a ridiculously long time for it to actually boot up. Just wait, or you could be impatient like me and the next thing you know you've got 3 AVDs on your screen

Comment: By the time John has written the question, the AVD would have probably booted up, don't you think?