# Cannot run Android application at all - not on the emulator and not on a real device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run my app, but it doesn't work at all. Not on the emulator and not on my Android device.

I am working with [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and when I open the [AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html) it doesn't open at all and I don't even see the process in the task manager.

I also tried to open `emulator.exe` and nothing happened. Basically, when I press run as Android application nothing happens.

How do I fix this problem?

P.S: I updated the Android SDK due the new Android version ([4.2 Jelly Bean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1.2F4.2_Jelly_Bean)) if it matters...

Comment: You are going to have to post at least a log error.

Comment: There is a very similar question here -

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425432/android-virtual-device-does-not-run/13425496#13425496

Comment: run in `cmd`: `adb devices` Do you see any device?

Comment: When I running adb device on the cmd.exe it says that 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: you should set environment path for adb command

Comment: How do I do that? and ADR..If I will delete eclipse And The SDK and actualyy everything, will I be able to open my projects again after I will reinstall the proggrams?